# Change Gender value in SQL table

Tags: sql-server

I have created a table in sql server and the tabel has Information of an Employee. There is a column to determine whether the Employee is male or female. i.e **Male** or **Female**. Now I need to convert all **Male**  to **Female** and all **Female** to **Male**?

*The table structure is:*

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
FName char(50), 
LName char(50), 
Address char(50),
Gender char(10),
Birth_Date date)
```

Comment: what is the data type of the male/female column?

Comment: @sharmile Can you post table structure?

Comment: @Andreas, The DataType is char

Comment: @Alex,The Table structure is shown below.CREATE TABLE Employee
(FName char(50),
LName char(50),
Address char(50),
Gender char(10),
Birth_Date date)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Freaky.

as a basic example, something like this:

```
update employees
set
    gender = case gender 
        when 'Male' then 'Female'
        when 'Female' then 'Male'
        else 'Other' end
```

Comment: +1 for other. Made me laugh. I think it's getting complicated

Comment: You'd be amazed (dismayed) at some of the personal data I've seen... nulls, blanks, really weird stuff... and of course, let's not assume there's only 2 genders in the universe!  As a general rule, having an `ELSE` clause in `CASE` statements can keep you out of trouble.

Comment: yeah you could do that too.  Since there was no requirement specified for the purposes of my example I made it "other".  That way the possible values on the column are well known.  Business requirements will determine how to actually handle that in a "real world" scenario.

Comment: Sex is an [ISO standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5218) and they use Not Applicable

Comment: Disturbing.  Apparently I am not ISO Compliant.  I like how they've reserved 3-8 for new genders that might show up.

Comment: Seriously?  Someone's going to downvote this after 8 months and not leave a comment?

Answer (score 5):

this should work:

```
UPDATE dbo.Employee
SET Gender =    
    CASE
        WHEN (Gender = 'Female')
            THEN 'Male'
        WHEN (Gender = 'Male')
            THEN 'Female'
    END
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this script

```
UPDATE [Employee]
SET [Gender] = CASE [Gender]
WHEN 'Male' THEN 'Female'
WHEN 'Female' THEN 'Male'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update employee
set gender=case when gender='Male' then 'Female'
when gender='female' then 'male' end
```